# MATE not showing up after install

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, mate

I just used Synaptic to install MATE Desktop Environment on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer.  It installed successfully, but after rebooting, it's not showing up on the login screen.  My only options are to choose from Ubuntu (Default) or XFCE.  Does anyone know why and how do I get MATE to work?

Comment: please add the output `apt-cache policy mate-desktop` and `apt-cache policy mate-desktop-environment`

Comment: The output of apt-cache policy mate-desktop is the following:
 apt-cache policy mate-desktop
mate-desktop:
  Installed: 1.6.2-1
  Candidate: 1.6.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.6.2-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


And the output of apt-cache policy mate-desktop-environment is:

Unable to locate package mate-desktop-environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mate-desktop

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

now add the MATE Official repo, press `y` when prompted.

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://repo.mate-desktop.org/archive/1.8/ubuntu trusty main"

sudo apt-get update
```

then install it:

```
sudo apt-get install mate-core

sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment

sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-extra

sudo reboot
```

Done.

Now you should be able to see `MATE` at the login screen.

Comment: Well, that worked, but my trackpad doesn't work in MATE.  In Unity or in XFCE I can tap on it to click or tap with two fingers to right-click.  Not even the mouse buttons work with it.  Even more interesting, though, the touchscreen on my laptop works in MATE.  Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: this I cannot tell, what I can tell you is every desktop is designed differently for its own features, maybe those features you use in `Unity` or `XFCE` can be activated in `MATE` too this is a question to MATE team developers, you can ask them [here](http://forums.mate-desktop.org/)

Comment: if your OP question has been solved, don't forget to accept it, thank you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is not totally correct. It installs Vanilla MATE, not Ubuntu MATE.

Follow the instructions on [install page of MATE desktop project](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

For Ubuntu versions later than 14.04 just simply install these packages, not adding reps (they are already in ubuntu reps).

Comment: The link is dead now. Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20190312120626/https://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download

Current instructions: https://www.google.com/search?q=Ubuntu+MATE+desktop+installation+instructions&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWtr2g-OryAhXTW80KHYPdDusQpwV6BAgBECQ&biw=1358&bih=1045