# install ubuntu mate over xubuntu 18.04 - not showing up

Tags: xubuntu, mate

I have done this :

```
apt install mate-desktop
apt install mate-common
apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop
apt install ubuntu-mate*
apt install mate-core
apt install mate-desktop-environment
apt install mate-desktop-environment-extra
```

From boot I see the MATE wallpaper but the frame  is Xubuntu. The login dialog does not offer the option of choosing desktops.

What have I missed? I do not need to keep Xubuntu desktop.

Tried these  :

http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download

[MATE not showing up after install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481104/mate-not-showing-up-after-install?rq=1)

**UPDATE**

I am working with a friend's old but very serviceable 32-bit laptop with 1 GB RAM so I'm pulling from the 32-bit repository. That may bring issues that people are not familiar with. Output below suggests a repository server problem, I think

```
apt-cache policy mate-desktop-environment
mate-desktop-environment:
Installed: 1.20.0+4
Candidate: 1.20.0+4
Version table:
*** 1.20.0+4 500
    500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 
Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Why not do a full install from fresh ?

Comment: @hatterman I have put some work into the setup already and then decided that Xubuntu wasn't what I wanted. I'm hoping to keep as much of my work as possible. I may do a side-by install and bind the home directory across the partition. That will save a lot.Thanks

Comment: I do not understand this phrase "but the frame is Xubuntu". What do you mean? Did you get success installing LightDM? Which sessions are available in it? Did you tried to switch to Main server (in Software & Updates)?

Comment: @N0rbert Sorry, bad wording. I don't know the correct term. I mean that  the login screen is the Xubuntu login screen except that it has the MATE wallpaper. Perhaps the installation of the MATE wallpapers set the default. LightDM returns with a warning. The man page refers to /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf but that does not exist. Instead there is an empty  lightdm.conf.d directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue on clean Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (on both 32-bit and 64-bit).

Try to purge `/etc/lightdm`-related packages with:

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm ubuntu-mate-lightdm-theme
```

and then install them again

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop lightdm ubuntu-mate-lightdm-theme
```

and then continue with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y --reinstall mate-desktop mate-common ubuntu-mate-desktop^ \
ubuntu-mate* mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-desktop-environment-extra \
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-text
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # get all new dependencies
```

Try to switch login screen to LightDM:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm # select lightdm
```

Also consider installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-default-settings mate-session-manager
```

Finally reboot and select MATE session in LightDM:

[image: MATE session in LightDM]

**Note:** usually steps above are not needed. I install MATE with
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`.

Comment: Not successful. I've edited my question with additional info.

Comment: I updated my answer. Still can't reproduce (started with netboot.iso, installed xubuntu-desktop and then ubuntu-mate-desktop with all packages mentioned in Q&A). Please try all steps carefully again. And of course I recommend to buy more RAM to the laptop for comfortable work.

Comment: The session manager I think did the trick. I am accustomed  to seeing the session selector on the login dialog but here you show me that it is on the top panel. All is well and now I don't know how long it's been well. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: It has acceptable performance with 1 GB. Unexpected. However I will look into upgrading memory and maybe put in a small SSD. It's quite a sturdy little machine. Well worth salvaging.